# C# Comparing two pieces of data

Tags: c#, testing

I'm running a test where i've executed a batch file for certain measures and it will give an output for the measures once the calculation is complete. I'm using specflow with the Given When and Then using C#.

On my final step for 'Then' i need to validate the data that is being outputted is correct. I've written code that will read the outputted data from a linux file (see below).  What i'll essentially be doing is comparing the data from the linux file for example (33, 554, 68) is same as what i'm expecting.

I've seen there is multiple ways to validate the actual data with the expected data. I've started with Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual) but wasn't sure whether i could hard code the expected output or compare it with data from an excel sheet. Which would be the easiest and best option?

```
 public string validateMeasurement(string measurementName, string domaianName)
    {
        var processFilePath = "/orabin/app/oracle/actuals/" + measurementName + ".csv.ovr";
        var actualItemData = Common.LinuxCommandExecutor.
            RunLinuxcommand("cat " + processFilePath);

        return actualItemData; 
    }

    public void validateMeasurement(string Data, string itemStatus)
    {
        var actual = 
        var expected =

            Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
```

Comment: your base data (what you are expecting) should be well tested and filed somewhere. (excel as you are saying). so it can be easily updated/changed (if changed data required in different cases) without disturbing actual test code.

Comment: If that is the case how would i make a call to the excel sheet to get the expected data?

Comment: that is whole new question. there are multiple ways to get data from excel.

Comment: In this example, what would be the most efficient way?

Comment: if you want to change (and keep updating) your expected data, then you can do excel (CSV will be better btw), but if your expected data is fixed and not going to change, you can hard-code it. Object serialization can also be helpful when your data is not suitable for tabular form (what we store in excel)

Comment: Yes my data won't be changing. I believe hard code would be the best way. For my 'var actual' how can i populate this so it retrieves the data from the linux file?

Comment: then go with the only answer posted here

Answer (score 0):

The only benefit I see to storing "expected" values in something like an excel sheet is avoiding recompilation if the expected value changes. Since anyone running the tests would have the ability to recompile the code; that doesn't seem like a big deal to me.

I would keep the answer easy to find and just hardcode it into the test (or a `TestCase` or framework equivalent, depending on if you have more than one).

Comment: So should i carry on as above. I understand how i can put the expected result but how can i populate the 'var actual' code?

Comment: @JOpenDock You read the file; that's a whole separate question.